# really odd behaviour in gulpjs

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have 2 files, a gulp file:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var babel = require("gulp‐babel");
var browserSync = require('browser‐sync');
var concat = require('gulp‐concat');
var eslint = require('gulp‐eslint');
var filter = require('gulp‐filter');
var newer = require('gulp‐newer');
var notify = require('gulp‐notify');
var plumber = require('gulp‐plumber');
var reload = browserSync.reload;
var less = require('gulp‐less');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp‐sourcemaps');



var onError = (err)=> {
    notify.onError({title: "Error",message: "<%= error %>",})(err);
    this.emit('end');
};

var plumberOptions = {errorHandler: onError};


gulp.task("test",()=>{

  onError("test error");

});
```

then a package file:

```
{
  "name": "testgulpfile",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-eslint": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-filter": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-less": "^3.3.0",
    "gulp-newer": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I (clearly I have run npm install) launch  "gulp test" or simply "gulp" from windows 10 or linux ubuntu, the follow error arise:

```
module.js 474

cannot find module 'gulp-babel' ...
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with these files.

Comment: What output did you get from `npm install`? What's in `node_modules`?

Comment: in node modules there are all modules described in package json, and during npm install nothing seem go wrong

Comment: @jonrsharpe I dunno why you clear the "thanks" at the end of the post, I'd like to be polite... by the way "Thanks" for your edit

Comment: @LXG http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having encoding issue:

I did this with your package names:

```
// Package name typed by keyboard
> encodeURI('gulp-sourcemaps')
'gulp-sourcemaps'

// Package name copied from your code (from gulpfile)
> encodeURI('gulp‐sourcemaps')
'gulp%E2%80%90sourcemaps'
```

Remove package names & type them from your keyboard
or
Just removing '-' & typing it from keyboard will work.